# JavaScript Async Function Does Not Return Expected Value (NodeJS app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am new to JavaScript (and Call Backs).
In my NodeJS App, I have created an Async function to go and retrieve some userdata from my SQL Database.
That works fine, the function DOES retrieve the Data.
Then, I am using BCrypt to check if the user supplied password matches the user's 'appPassword'.

This work too!

However, when the password match is successful (OR unsuccessful) I try and return a JSON Object back to the calling function, but the 'result' in the calling function is ALWAYS 'undefined'
I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Could a JavaScript expert please help?

I have posted my code (Async function and Calling function) below:

NB: The 'result' in the Calling function is ALWAYS 'undefined'

## ASYNC FUNCTION

```
async function VerifyUserByUsernamePassword(userEmail, password) {

    const sql = require('mssql')
    const { configMSSQL } = require("./db.config.js");

    if (sql) sql.close();

    return await sql.connect(configMSSQL).then(async pool => {

        // Stored procedure
        let output_parameter
        return await pool.request()
            .input('Email', sql.NVarChar, userEmail)
            // .output('output_parameter', sql.Int)
            .execute('API_READ_USER_BY_EMAIL')

    }).then(async result => {
        sql.close();
        // sql = null;
        if (result.recordset.length > 0) {

            const appPassword = result.recordset[0].appPassword;

            bcrypt.compare(password, appPassword, async function (err, result2) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return ({
                        "message": "failed"
                    })
                }
                if (!result2) {
                    // console.log("result2", result2)
                    return ({
                        "message": "failed"
                    })
                }
                console.log("result2 was True")
                return ({
                    "message": "success",
                    "data": result
                })
            })

        } else {
            console.log("Error retrieving User Records for Login Verification......");
            return ({
                "message": "failed"
            })
        }

    }).catch(err => {
        sql.close();
        // ... error checks
        console.log("Error retrieving User Records for Login Verification", err);
        return ({
            "message": "failed"
        });
    });

}
```

## CALLING FUNCTION

```
exports.VerifyLogin = async (req, res) => {

    var errors = []

    if (!req.body.email) {
        errors.push("Credentials Missing");
    }
    if (!req.body.password) {
        errors.push("Credentials Missing");
    }

    if (errors.length) {
        res.status(400).json({ "error": errors.join(",") });
        return;
    }

    var email = req.body.email
    var password = req.body.password

    const { VerifyUserByUsernamePassword } = require("../database/mssqldb.js");

    await VerifyUserByUsernamePassword(email, password).then(async result => {

        if (result && result.message === "success") {

            res.json(result.data);

        } else {
            res.json({
                "message": "failed",
                "User Record ": email
            },);
        }

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);

        res.json({
            "message": "error",
            "User Record ": email
        },)
    })

}
```

Comment: You’ve got a horrible mix of then and await. Your code would be much easier to debug if you **just** used await.

Comment: The branch “ if (result.recordset.length > 0) {” - has no return statement. (The one in the callback belongs to the callback)